# Possessive case

Tags: possessives

Should I say:

*The spacing between pattern instances for plane X direction*

or:

*The spacing between pattern instances for plane's X direction*

or there isn't much difference after all?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There must be an article before *plane* (or *plane's*), but which one depends on the context.

- If *plane* is purely an adjective (that is, the X direction is flat), then it's not inflected.
- If *plane* is a noun and the "X direction" is that **of the plane,** it's probably better to indicate that relationship with the possessive.

There is not enough context in the quote to be more specific, either about the article or the possessive; hopefully this will be enough to allow you to make the decisions.

Comment: Here I'm talking about the [cartesian plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system)...

Comment: OK... so you need *the* and the possessive.

Comment: I would read the first option as referring to one of a number of planes in a higher dimentional space and would expect to see reference to at least one other plane (possibly plane Y) at an angle to X later in the same document. The second option makes it clear that you are referring to the X direction of one [X:Y] plane, but you do need to say 'the plane'.